# Is it possible to send variables from HTML to another PHP file

Tags: php, html

I have a index.html where I would like to submit some coordinates that can be passed upon to separate PHP file; where it could perform a query. I am new to this.

HTML:

```
    Xmax<input type="text" name="Xmax" size="15">
    Ymax<input type="text" name="Ymax" size="15">
    <input type=SUBMIT name="submit" VALUE="Submit">
```

PHP query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM state WHERE LONG_HI<$_POST["Ymax"] AND LAT_HI<$_POST["Xmax"];
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

So is there a way to perform remote action from this HTML file to the specified PHP file?

Comment: NEVER use POST variables in PHP directly in an SQL query, without proper escaping. Search 'sql injection' on wikipedia for a proper explanation and solution! Not doing this WILL result in your site getting hacked soon.

Comment: Yeah, you definitely need to escape. A good start is to insert `mysql_escape_string($_POST['whatever'])` instead of just the POST variable. Also, if the variables should only be numbers, you should probably test them with `is_numeric()` first and die with some message if they aren't, just for added safety.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Forms can do the job. Is'nt it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes

Either make an HTML form to accept the Xmax and Ymax parameters, and set the form action to the PHP file;

Or use AJAX to pass the data in the background and receive a response.

If both of these concepts are foreign to you, and you don't know JavaScript, get comfortable with the first option first.

Comment: well how to set form action to remote php file??!

Comment: Imre has that. However if you are serious about this, might I recommend: http://www.w3schools.com/html/

Answer (score 0):

Would you please describe in detail what you are about to do?

- do you have a html form?
- What kind of request do you do, clicking a link, sending the form?
- The query does not contain any of the variables...

could you please post excerpts of the code? single lines are useless in most cases.

Regards,
Mario

Comment: Well I edited my question clearly now.. cud u have a look now!
I was trying to send form variables to a remote php file but I am not sure how

Answer (score 0):

use action attribute in FORM element to specify where the request will be sent to.

```
<form action="another.php" method="POST">
    Xmax<input type="text" name="Xmax" size="15">
    Ymax<input type="text" name="Ymax" size="15">
    <input type=SUBMIT name="submit" VALUE="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: By this way when I click submit button I am  being redirected to the php file along  with the varibles to perform query.. 
But I wish to remain in the index.html page & just passon the variables to the php

Comment: Either use <a href="http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/">ajax</a> or place your php code before your html code in index.html and rename that file to index.php. Then you call "index.php" instead of "another.php"

Comment: Then you can either use AJAX or redirect back to index.html from the another.php calling `header('Location: index.html');` after youre done in there.

Answer (score 0):

You just add few line with your code because to transfer any variable value from one form to another page we have to use 'form' method. So, we have to add form tag with your code. Transferring of data from one page to another page (any type of page like php, jsp, aspx etc) is done by two methods mainly - one of them is Post and another one is Get.

Difference between both the method is quite simple. In Post method, data from one page to another page travels in hidden form whereas Get is basically used to transfer value by displaying it at url. Post method example: user-name and password, and Get Method: any query fired at Search Engine.

```
<form name="form" action="filename.php" method="POST" >
    //Your Code 
</form>
```